# Get localStorage items (numbers) and add them together

Tags: javascript, local-storage

**Context**

- I am not a developer
- I want to use Vanilla JS (no JQuery)

I'm using the following code and it is giving me the desired outcome, however I'd like to improve the code and make it more efficient if possible.

**Working code**

```
var score_A1 = localStorage.getItem("score_A1");
var score_A2 = localStorage.getItem("score_A2");
var score_A3 = localStorage.getItem("score_A3");
var score_A4 = localStorage.getItem("score_A4");
var score_A5 = localStorage.getItem("score_A5");
a =+ score_A1;
b =+ score_A2;
c =+ score_A3;
d =+ score_A4;
e =+ score_A5;
var scoreTotal_A = a + b + c + d + e;
```

I am then using innerHTML and calling `${scoreTotal_A}` to display the total.

**Questions**

- Is there a 'better', more efficient way to code this?
- Is there a way to code it to GET and ADD together any localStorage item that begins with `score_A`?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `.key()` method to iterate through local storage keys:

```
function sumScores() {
  let key, sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; (key = localStorage.key(i)) != null; ++i)
    if (/^score_A/.test(key))
      sum += +localStorage.getItem(key);
  return sum;
}
```

Then call it like

```
console.log("All A score total: " + sumScores());
```

Comment: Hey! This is exactly the sort of solution I was after. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Given you're not a developer, I assume efficiency means readability in your case. You haven't posted code for where you call `localStorage.setItem()`, but I could see this code looking a lot cleaner if you just store the first score in one key in localStorage (e.g. `score_A`) and then add the remaining scores to that value instead of assigning them to separate keys.

Then you could just retrieve the calculated total instead of retrieving each score and adding them up again.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you mean by "effective". That code executes well.